# how to use freezegun on logbook

Tags: python, pytest, freezegun, logbook

I'm trying to run tests that involve mocking datetime within logbook (for logic around `logbook.TimedRotatingFileHandler`). But freezegun doesn't reach logbook. Logs print as the current (un-mocked, correct) current time!

my example prints the confusing message

```
[2019-07-09 22:01:21.583288] INFO: None: test time: 2000-01-01 00:01:00
```

for the following pytest

```
from freezegun import freeze_time
import logbook
import sys
import datetime as dt

def test_logbook():
    faketime = freeze_time('2000-01-01 00:01')
    faketime.start()
    assert dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%d%m') == '20000101'
    log = logbook.Logger()
    log.handlers.append(logbook.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
    log.info('test time: ' + str(dt.datetime.now()))
    faketime.stop()
    assert 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are freezing time after the import of `logbook`, not covering some init on module level. Move the import inside the scope with time frozen; example:

```
from freezegun import freeze_time
import sys
import datetime as dt

def test_logbook(capsys):
    with freeze_time('2000-01-01 00:01'):
        import logbook
        assert dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%d%m') == '20000101'
        log = logbook.Logger()
        log.handlers.append(logbook.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
        log.info('hello world')
    assert capsys.readouterr().out == '[2000-01-01 00:01:00.000000] INFO: None: hello world\n'
```

Comment: awesome! if i run that test with --noconftest, it passes. My configtest.py imports a file (with functions i'm testing) that imports logbook - so I don't think I can get feezetime before the import. Maybe this is a different question. Also thanks for capsys. didn't know about that!

Comment: Glad I could help! Freezing time globally can be indeed tricky and sometimes even require dynamic imports (via `importlib`), but surely doable. I usually define and start a global freezer in the `pytest_configure` hook and move all the affected imports like `datetime` inside the fixtures/hooks, then stop the freezer in `pytest_unconfigure`. If you post an [mcve] in a new question, I'll be happy to help.